# Addition for array values

Tags: php, arrays

I have problems with my array where the values inside the array doesn't want to add (+1) when the data is equal to the data inside database.

Can someone help me, thanks.
Sorry for bad english/grammar.

Case Example:

```
A B C D E // answer
0 0 0 0 0 // count
0 1 0 0 0 // user answer B
1 1 0 0 0 // user answer A
1 2 0 0 0 // user answer B again
```

Code:

```
//create an array with values 0
$tempAns = array_fill(0,5,0);

//loop for every answered
foreach ($_POST['ques'] as $key){
    //loop for every answer from DB
    foreach ($_POST['ans_item'] as $value){
        //if answered same with answer from DB (answer is stored inside DB) 
        if($key == $value)
            //values in array will +1, depends on the node 0-4
            $tempAns++;
    }
}
```

Comment: `$tempAns` is an array, i.e. a list of values, each value accessible using a key (which are the integer numbers `0` to `5` in your case). `$tempAns++` doesn't make any sense. The `++` operator applies only to numbers. Read about [PHP arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Comment: @axiac yeah, its pretty weird.. :( sorry..how can i add the values?

Comment: Have you read the documentation? On the section ["Accessing array elements"](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.accessing) it explains how to access individual array elements. Since the elements are integer numbers you can use `++` with them.

Comment: @axiac Yeah I have read, but I still can't configure it well.

Comment: Write a small script using the examples from the documentation. Use `print_r()` often in the test script to understand how arrays (and programming, in general) work. You keep saying something about a database but there is no sign of any database in the code you posted.

Comment: @axiac erm, I already comments on the code. Should I post a full code.. :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is the logic behind your implementation but I think the following can help you out:

```
$tempAns = array ( "A" => 0, "B" => 0, "C" => 0, "D" => 0, "E" => 0);

foreach(_$POST['ques'] as $key) {
   $tempAns[$key]++;
}
```

it assumes that `ques` contains something like:

```
ques = {"A", "A", "B", "E", ...}
```

Comment: but I need to compare the answered question (post values) with the answer inside the database. Because I need to calculate total for each answer that had been pick. *Assumes that we don't know how many answer for each question. (Maybe only A and B, Maybe A, B, and C.) So we read it from the database, thats why I use the second foreach.

Comment: @nyc2x in your question you used, array_fill(0,5,0) which you have already limited your array to have 5 values

Comment: I know, sorry.. I'm just filling up (tryout) because the data stored contains 5 answer.

Comment: @nyc2x user answers multiple questions or just one question multiple times?

Comment: @nyc2x have this solution finally helped you?

Answer (score 0):

Finally after a few tries by combining @Pooya answer:

```
$size = $_POST['tempVar'] + 1;
$tempArray = array_fill(0, $size, 0);

echo "<br />";
foreach ($_POST['ques'] as $key){
    $a=0;
    foreach ($ans_item as $value){
        if($key == $value){
            $tempArray[$a]++;
        }
        $a++;
    }
}
```

Thanks @Pooya!

Also thanks for those who downrate my Post!